# Transposing Columns to Rows Using only Case Statement and Joining All Tables

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, case, transpose, rdbms

I have a query that produces millions of rows and has 10s of columns. I have posted a pic of the original query and it's a simplied version of what I am working with and is named '*Details*'.

I need to transpose each row/value in the column 'Description' to separate columns and transpose the columns: **CountValue**, **AmountA** and **AmountB** into 3 separate tables, each having their own columns from the '**Description**' column. Finally I need to join them all into one table.

This is the original Table *Details*:

[image: Table Details]

I have transposed each value from 'Description' into their own column and have transposed 'CountValue' under one column and populated every row with it. This is the Table *Counts*:

[image: Table Counts]

Here I have done the same for AmountA. This is Table *AmtA*:

[image: AmtA]

The same transpose has been done for Table *AmtB*:

[image: AmtB]

And finally join them all together in Table *AmountCount*, which needs to be my final output:

[image: AmountCount]

Few things to note:

- I can only use case statements and aggregate function. I can't use pivot function or other more complex functions.
- The above tables are just a sample of what I actually want to work with which has millions of rows and multitudes of columns.
- I want all the transposed tables, and the resultant table to be in the same order as the original table.

The query I tried to transpose the columns CountValue and Description from the table Counts is here:

```
with Counts as
    (
        select distinct
        t1.CountsA,
        t1.CountsB,
        t1.CountsC
        t1.CountsD,
        ('CountValue') as ColCountE,
        sum(case when Description = 'Arizona' then t1.CountValue end) as ColArizona,
        sum(case when Description = 'California ' then t1.CountValue end) as ColCalifornia,
        sum(case when Description = 'Florida' then t1.CountValue end) as ColFlorida,
        sum(case when Description = 'Iowa' then t1.CountValue end) as ColIowa,
        sum(case when Description = 'Kansas ' then t1.CountValue end) as ColKansas,
        sum(case when Description = 'Kentucky' then t1.CountValue end) as ColKentucky

        from Details t1
        group by t1.CountsA,
        t1.CountsB,
        t1.CountsC
        t1.CountsD,
        CountValue
    )
SELECT * from Counts
```

I tried various combinations of group by, including the above but I'm not getting the required results. Appreciate if anyone can provide the right code. This is the main code I need, any suggestions with using case statement for transposing.

My other question is regarding combining all the transposed tables. Let's say the columns **CountsA** and **CountsB**, which are present in every table, are the keys. In the final table, is it fine if I keep all the required columns in select, then inner join **CountsA** and **CountsB** across the tables *Counts*, *AmtA* and *AmtB* ?

Comment: Please read this and edit accordingly: [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055)

Comment: Add tag for RDBMS used. Why not use images https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: If you use Access database, review http://allenbrowne.com/ser-67.html#MultipleValues

Comment: "not getting the required results" means what - error message, wrong result, nothing happens? Why would you need to use subquery? Don't mix DISTINCT with GROUP BY.

Comment: More about join. At least one query must have all possible key values present. Otherwise, need to join those 3 queries to another dataset that does have all key values.

Comment: @June7 By that I mean under the transposed columns I'm getting the wrong value. I'll remove distinct. Thanks foe the help about join and regarding formatting I'll edit everything soon.

Comment: @June7 so regarding subquery it was merely a continuation something I did previously I erroneously put it here. I just need to know if the group by clause is right. I saw many questions that answered transpose and they used case statements inside sum or max but I couldn't figure what to put inside group by in my specific case.

Comment: GROUP BY must include every field from SELECT that is not an aggregation. So don't include CountValue in either SELECT (As ColCountE) or GROUP BY because this is the data you want to aggregate. CountValue should be referenced only in the aggregate calcs.

Comment: Tag "rdbms" does not specify the RDBMS you are working with. Is this MySQL, SQLServer, or what? Also, the data manipulation you want is a "pivot".

Comment: @June7 I've included the rdbms. So you mean to say I need to include CountValue as a sum(case when) statement as well. Counts A-D in select, then everything else including CountValue and the columns from 'Description' in sum(case when) then group by A to D right? And I didn't know this was called pivot thanks, I was only aware of the function.

Comment: I mean what I said. Don't reference CountValue in SELECT except in the Sum() expressions you already have and not in GROUP BY. Review https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/pivot

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pivot multiple aggregation in Snowflake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69017226/how-to-pivot-multiple-aggregation-in-snowflake)

Comment: Actually, should be able to do these conditional calcs all in one query. Just need 18 Sum() expressions. I should have seen that long ago.

Comment: In SQL `case when .. then ... else ... end` is properly known as a **case expression** because they resolve to scalar value (per row). A "statement" is quite different (e.g. a select statement, an update statement)

Comment: From site [help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) **DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc**.—copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. For more information please see the Meta FAQ entry [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557)

Comment: @June7 Thanks for the help I got it resolved. The one thing I need to look into more is group by and partitions. Looking at more data will probably help.

Answer (score 0):

It will not be efficient to run 3 different queries and then join those results, just keep adding more **case expressions** to cover all the amount columns. So you would not need `('CountValue') as ColCountE` (or similar) in the select clause because all numeric columns can be catered for in the one query, and the column names imply the data source. (You may want to revisit the naming of the columns to make this more clear.)

```
SELECT
      t1.CountsA
    , t1.CountsB
    , t1.CountsC
    , t1.CountsD
    /* CountValue */
    , sum(CASE WHEN Description = 'Arizona' THEN t1.CountValue END) AS ColArizona
    , sum(CASE WHEN Description = 'California ' THEN t1.CountValue END) AS ColCalifornia
    , sum(CASE WHEN Description = 'Florida' THEN t1.CountValue END) AS ColFlorida
    , sum(CASE WHEN Description = 'Iowa' THEN t1.CountValue END) AS ColIowa
    , sum(CASE WHEN Description = 'Kansas ' THEN t1.CountValue END) AS ColKansas
    , sum(CASE WHEN Description = 'Kentucky' THEN t1.CountValue END) AS ColKentucky
    /* AmountA */
    , sum(CASE WHEN Description = 'Arizona' THEN t1.AmountA END) AS Arizona_A
    , sum(CASE WHEN Description = 'California ' THEN t1.AmountA END) AS California_A
    , sum(CASE WHEN Description = 'Florida' THEN t1.AmountA END) AS Florida_A
    , sum(CASE WHEN Description = 'Iowa' THEN t1.AmountA END) AS Iowa_A
    , sum(CASE WHEN Description = 'Kansas ' THEN t1.AmountA END) AS Kansas_A
    , sum(CASE WHEN Description = 'Kentucky' THEN t1.AmountA END) AS Kentucky_A
    /* AmountB */
    , sum(CASE WHEN Description = 'Arizona' THEN t1.AmountB END) AS Arizona_B
    , sum(CASE WHEN Description = 'California ' THEN t1.AmountB END) AS California_B
    , sum(CASE WHEN Description = 'Florida' THEN t1.AmountB END) AS Florida_B
    , sum(CASE WHEN Description = 'Iowa' THEN t1.AmountB END) AS Iowa_B
    , sum(CASE WHEN Description = 'Kansas ' THEN t1.AmountB END) AS Kansas_B
    , sum(CASE WHEN Description = 'Kentucky' THEN t1.AmountB END) AS Kentucky_B
FROM Details t1
GROUP BY
      t1.CountsA
    , t1.CountsB
    , t1.CountsC
    , t1.CountsD
```

**Notes**

- Using **case expressions** inside an aggregate function is known as "conditional aggregation"
- the `group by` clause will form unique rows from the columns you specify in that clause, `select distinct` also tests if all rows are uniquely defined - so it is redundant if already using `group by`.
- do not include columns that you need to aggregate into the `group by` clause, the columns you do include are sometimes known as "non-aggregating" columns
- there are 2 missing commas in the sql of your question, this a reason why I prefer the layout seen above. Try it out at [PoorSQL](http://poorsql.com/?inputString=SELECT+t1.CountsA%0A++++%2C+t1.CountsB%0A++++%2C+t1.CountsC+t1.CountsD%0A%2F*+CountValue+*%2F%0A++++%2C+sum(CASE+WHEN+Description+%3D+%27Arizona%27+THEN+t1.CountValue+END)+AS+ColArizona%0A++++%2C+sum(CASE+WHEN+Description+%3D+%27California+%27+THEN+t1.CountValue+END)+AS+ColCalifornia%0A++++%2C+sum(CASE+WHEN+Description+%3D+%27Florida%27+THEN+t1.CountValue+END)+AS+ColFlorida%0A++++%2C+sum(CASE+WHEN+Description+%3D+%27Iowa%27+THEN+t1.CountValue+END)+AS+ColIowa%0A++++%2C+sum(CASE+WHEN+Description+%3D+%27Kansas+%27+THEN+t1.CountValue+END)+AS+ColKansas%0A++++%2C+sum(CASE+WHEN+Description+%3D+%27Kentucky%27+THEN+t1.CountValue+END)+AS+ColKentucky%0A%2F*+AmountA+*%2F%0A++++%2C+sum(CASE+WHEN+Description+%3D+%27Arizona%27+THEN+t1.AmountA+END)+AS+Arizona_A%0A++++%2C+sum(CASE+WHEN+Description+%3D+%27California+%27+THEN+t1.AmountA+END)+AS+California_A%0A++++%2C+sum(CASE+WHEN+Description+%3D+%27Florida%27+THEN+t1.AmountA+END)+AS+Florida_A%0A++++%2C+sum(CASE+WHEN+Description+%3D+%27Iowa%27+THEN+t1.AmountA+END)+AS+Iowa_A%0A++++%2C+sum(CASE+WHEN+Description+%3D+%27Kansas+%27+THEN+t1.AmountA+END)+AS+Kansas_A%0A++++%2C+sum(CASE+WHEN+Description+%3D+%27Kentucky%27+THEN+t1.AmountA++END)+AS+Kentucky_A%0AFROM+Details+t1%0AGROUP+BY+t1.CountsA%0A++++%2C+t1.CountsB%0A++++%2C+t1.CountsC%0A++++%2C+t1.CountsD%0A&expandCommaLists=true&trailingCommas=false&spaceAfterExpandedComma=true&expandBooleanExpressions=false&expandCaseStatements=false&expandBetweenConditions=false&expandInLists=false&breakJoinOnSections=false&uppercaseKeywords=true&coloring=true&keywordStandardization=false&randomizeColor=false&randomizeLineLengths=false&randomizeKeywordCase=false&preserveComments=false&enableKeywordSubstitution=false&formattingType=standard&indent=%5Cs%5Cs%5Cs%5Cs&spacesPerTab=4&maxLineWidth=999&statementBreaks=2&clauseBreaks=1&language=&reFormat=true&obfuscate=false) e.g. look for "trailing comma" in the options